# How can I set Session engine?

Tags: django

While trying to use cookies, I have trying to follow the vendor's documentation. In the documentation, I have seen this sentence `Set SESSION_ENGINE to "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache" for a simple caching
session store.`
 but I could not find the place to change the session settings. How can I set Session engine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you done the tutorial yet? If not, it's a very good place to start.

All Django settings are in the [`project/settings.py` file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/).

**Update for comment:**

The default settings are in `django/conf/global_settings.py`. ***DO NOT*** modify this file! All of the settings in there can be overridden in your project's `settings.py` file.

Comment: I understand. But, in the file, there is no SESSION_ENGINE. But, the tutorial says that at default, it is setted. I have wondered where it is setted. But I have not found the place. So I have asked.

Answer (score 16):

Just try to put in the `settings.py`

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Comment: Should I put it at anywhere or on some specified place in the settings.py ?

Comment: See if you already have `SESSION_ENGINE` in your settings.py. If you do, replace it, if not, you can put it anywhere

Comment: @JeffS I do not have. Thanks

Comment: Then you can add that anywhere in the settings.py file